# Connecting to remote ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop

I installed ubuntu desktop 12.04 on my server, but I want to be able to connect using vnc from my mac.

I cannot login to the desktop as its at a different physical location, I only have ssh at my disposal...how do I setup my remote ubuntu install to allow remote desktop connections so I can use the desktop environment remotely?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know your own external ip address, I can offer this quick solution:

You want to install openssh-server on your server like so:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Then, you need to forward port 22 in your router to your server, in order to access your it from the outside.

Comment: I'm asking about how to do a remote desktop connetion, not ssh. I can already do ssh.